# overview on all stages and theatres that play a. Bertolt Brecht b. W. Shakespeare

Tags: data-request, calendar

I need an overview on all stages and theatres that play:

a. Bertolt Brecht

b. William Shakespeare

I am interested to find out all stages in the USA and Europe.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of all venues which have staged plays by both playwrights? Given the vast number of such venues, I doubt such a dataset is immediately available. For current playwrights whose work still requires licensing, you might be able to collect information about who has paid for a license, although it's not "open data" in any way. Otherwise, you would have to scrape lots of theater websites, I guess.